# UITextfield / UITextView native edit menu is cropped

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

The native edit menu for all the UITextFields and UITextViews in the app is cropped in >= iOS 16.
The menu is cropped and scrolling to the most right doesn't stick, so the last buttons are unreachable.

[image]
[image]

This only reproduces in my app for any device / simulator, doesn't happen to any other apps and doesn't reproduce with the previous iOS versions.

Have anyone encountered this problem as well?